# Memory leakage when trying to remove an object in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, memory-leaks

I have a dynamically allocated array and I am trying to remove a chosen object from it. But I end up with memory leakage.
Array:

```
Competitor* *person;
```

Which is allocated:

```
person = new Competitor*[capacity];
for (int i = 0; i < this->capacity; i++) {
    person[i] = nullptr;
}
```

This is my removal function:

```
bool Handler::removeCompetitor(string name) {
    bool removed = false;
    if (find(name) != -1) {
        Competitor* *temp = new Competitor*[capacity];
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfCompetitors; i++) {
            if (person[i] != person[find(name)]) {
                temp[j] = person[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        delete[] person;

        nrOfCompetitors -= 1;
        person = temp;
        removed = true;
    }
    return removed;
}
```

And this is my find function:

```
int Handler::find(string name) const {
    int found = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfCompetitors; i++) {
        if (person[i]->getName() == name) {
            found = i;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

The class "Competitor" is an abstract base class.
Why do I end up with memory leakage?

Comment: You're over complicating. You can save yourself a lot of work by keeping the existing array, finding the location of the person to be removed, and moving all persons after the person to be removed up one slot in the array..

Comment: Since it looks like you are storing pointers to `Competitor`s, you likely need to `delete` the removed person as well as the old array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the `Competitor*` from the array by creating a new array that does not include the `Competitor*`, you very likely need to `delete` the `Competitor *`.

Right before `delete[] person;` add `delete person[find(name)];`

If you really want to be sneaky, up at the top `found = find(name);` and use `found` instead of re-finding name over and over.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but you were right. I was over complicating it. The code is shorter now with no leakages.